# How to avoid one DIV overflowing the other?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hello I have the following code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6epuquqj/))

```
    #statements {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.4);
  max-width: 340px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}  

#entries {
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  max-width: inherit;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#entryform {
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  width: 340px;
}
```

and

```
<div id="statements">
  <div id="entries">entry</div>
  <div id="entryform">entryform</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I cannot make `entries` stop before `entryform` starts (also should be responsive to browser height).

Any idea how I could make `entries` not overflow the `entryform` div?

Thanks!

Comment: `#entryform` is fixed. If you want `#entries` to stop before a fixed element you'll need some js calculations going on.

Comment: What if it was absolute? @KaiQing

Comment: Absolute would give you similar effects except the bottom:0 would be relative to the parent and not the view, as you have declared #statements with 100vh - not 100% sure why you would do that. I think we would need to know your end goal to know how you should restructure this

Comment: I agree that this sounds like a strange way to build your page. Are you trying to build a [Sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)? It doesn't look like `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

ENTRYFORM has position:fixed... which means that it is removed from the 'flow' of the document. This causes ENTRIES to not effect ENTRYFORM .

To get ENTRYFORM to always be below of ENTRIES, I would add height: 40% to ENTRYFORM .

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what your overall goal here is, but if you always want #entryform to be 300px and for #entries to take up the remaining space try this:

```
#entries {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:300px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below:

```
#entryform {
  position: fixed;
  height: 40%;
   top: 60%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  width: 340px;
}
```

so basically you are saying let the other div take the rest height and make its top start from 60% from the top which is the top div height. Try it. 
This has been testing on